# Get the abstract class current instance and use the instance to call specific child class properties in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, properties, abstract

I'm not sure if the title is confusing, feel free to edit it.

I have the following sample code

```
public abstract class A 
{
    public int P1 {get; set;}

}

public class B : A 
{
    public int p2 {get; set;}
}

public class C : A
{
    public int p2 {get; set;}
}


public class test 
{
A a = null;

public test(A a1)
{
  a = a1;
}

public void foo()
{
    if((a as B)!=null)
    {
        (a as B).p2 = 1;
    }
    else if ((a as C)!=null)
    {
        (a as C).p2 = 2;
    }
}
```

}

P2 doen't not exist in the abstract class only some inheritance of the class will have it. For me to set this property i need to check if the current instance is of type Class B or C and than I will set the property. Every time I will add a class that it has this property I need to add a check for it. Is there a way just to grab the instance and check if P2 exist than set it without checking every type.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options, none of which are ideal:

Options that are not compile-time safe:

- use reflection to see if the object has a `p2` property (and set it if it does)
- use `dynamic` and deal with any exceptions at run-time

Options that require changes to your class design

- create an intermediate type that inherits from `A` and has a `p2` property and cast to that type
- define an interface with a `p2` property that `B` and `C` both implement and try to cast to that interface.

Comment: if P2 is an instance of another class how  for example public ClassType P2 {get;set;}  using reflection how to call the method from P2  like P2.F00()

Comment: foreach (var property in A.GetType().GetProperties())
                {  if (property.Name == "p2")
                    { property.Foo()??? }}

Comment: You'd have to get the value from that property and cast it to the right type, or use reflection and/or `dynamic` _again_.